# Django 2.2 with external connection SQL SERVER

Tags: python, django, django-mssql-backend

In my python 3.7 + Django 2.2 I need to connect to external SQL Server. Its not the main DB of Django (that remains in Postgres). I only need to make some query on a view.

Im on Debian 9 and Im trying to install package to add sql server connection but I cant find on google a guide about Debian package to install.

I try to install:

```
pip install pyodbc
pip install django-mssql-backend
```

but the compile failed. I think Im missing some system libraries.

UPDATE 1

```
apt-get install unixodbc-dev
pip install pyodbc
pip install django-mssql-backend
```

This solved the library installation. Now I got problem when trying to connect to DB:

```
Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the underlying drivers which allow `unixodbc` to connect to SQL Server. [You can find instructions to install the Microsoft ODBC driver here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

The short version for Debian, from the link:

```sh
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version

#Debian 8
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/8/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

#Debian 9
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

#Debian 10
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
# optional: kerberos library for debian-slim distributions
sudo apt-get install libgssapi-krb5-2
```

Good luck!